# Firefox/Chrome compatibility: HTML table with fixed header and column

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a page with an HTML table and some CSS.  When I display the page in **Firefox** (v66.0.5 64-bit) then it mostly works, the headers stick to the top like they are supposed to and the first column sticks to the left. But when I shrink the width of the browser window so the page has a horizontal scrollbar, I can't figure out how to make the `tr` tag with a `colspan` not scroll off to the left when scrolling horizontally.

When I run the same code in Firefox using **JSFiddle**, it doesn't work as well as from my own HTML and CSS files. The only header that sticks to the top is the main one with the column headers, the other headers don't stick to the top.  However, the first column *does* stick to the left.  Here's the page on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/samlalani/nswoz9rp/8/

The same issue occurs on **Safari** on MacOS.

In **Chrome** (v74.0.3729.131 64-bit), the first column sticks to the left when scrolling horizontally, but scrolling vertically doesn't stick *any* headers at the top.

I have been searching all over the internet (including on **stackoverflow**) trying to figure out how to make this page work on both Firefox *and* Chrome with no luck. And there are no examples of how to make a `tr` with a `colspan` not scroll off the left of the screen when scrolling horizontally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I am using:

```css
.scrollingtable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20;
}

.mytable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 850px;
  left: 0;
}

.nameheader {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.name {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

.date {
  width: 65;
}

.city {
  width: 80px;
}

.state {
  width: 30px;
}

.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mytitle {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  height: 50;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 5;
}

.subtitle {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  height: 20;
  top: 50;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #555;
  z-index: 4;
}

.subtitle2 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  height: 20;
  top: 70;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  background-color: #AAA;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="th.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollingtable">
    <table class="mytable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="mytitle">
          <th class="nameheader">Name</th>
          <th class="date">Date</th>
          <th class="city">City</th>
          <th class="state">State</th>
          <th class="date">Date</th>
          <th class="city">City</th>
          <th class="state">State</th>
          <th class="date">Date</th>
          <th class="city">City</th>
          <th class="state">State</th>
          <th class="date">Date</th>
          <th class="city">City</th>
          <th class="state">State</th>
          <th class="date">Date</th>
          <th class="city">City</th>
          <th class="state">State</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle">
          <td colspan="16">Managers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle">
          <td colspan="16">Developers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle2">
          <td colspan="16">SubStaff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle">
          <td colspan="16">Staff 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle2">
          <td colspan="16"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle">
          <td colspan="16">Staff 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle2">
          <td colspan="16">SubStaff 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subtitle">
          <td colspan="16">Staff 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">John Doe</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Jill Smith</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bob Whitaker</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Bill Allec</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
          <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
          <td class="city">Las Vegas</td>
          <td class="state">NV</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, on Chrome, the "**position:sticky**" style does not work if it is attached to a **tr** tag, but it works if it is attached to a **th** or **td**.  In Firefox, the style *does* work when attached to a **tr**.